# Not able to install loader in Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I'm trying to follow a getting started guide, of installing a npm package called [Vux](https://github.com/airyland/vux). It's basically a UI written in Vue.js. The guide says that i need to modify a Webpack config file to include vux loader. Everything looks pretty straight-forward, my config file should looke like that:

```
const vuxLoader = require('vux-loader')
const webpackConfig = originalConfig

module.exports = vuxLoader.merge(webpackConfig, {
  plugins: ['vux-ui']
})
```

I have a plain Webpacker config file generated by Rails/Webpacker and, after following a doc, it looks like that:

```
# config/webpack/environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const vuxLoader = require('vux-loader')

module.exports = vuxLoader.merge(environment, {
  plugins: ['vux-ui']
})
```

You can see that file on git hub [here](https://github.com/mbajur/hcpl/blob/mobile/config/webpack/environment.js)

However, after that change, Webpack throws:

```
/Volumes/SUPPORT/Workspace/Personal/hcpl/node_modules/vux-loader/src/index.js:285
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                   ^

TypeError: config.plugins.push is not a function
    at Function.module.exports.merge (/Volumes/SUPPORT/Workspace/Personal/hcpl/node_modules/vux-loader/src/index.js:285:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/SUPPORT/Workspace/Personal/hcpl/config/webpack/environment.js:7:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/SUPPORT/Workspace/Personal/hcpl/config/webpack/development.js:1:83)
```

Does anyone have any idea what have i done wrong in here? I'm not too experienced with Webpack nor the Webpacker setup makes it even more complicated to find/test any solution from the internet.